# Online administration tool

Tags: debian, ubuntu, remote, remote-management, webmin

do you know any solutions like webmin for my ubuntu/debian box? I want to control some of my machines over network via HTTP. Is there any solution that will provide me with a dashboard? Even better if it will support multiple boxes.

*EDIT: I got many debian/ubuntu boxes with the same configuration. So I need to a dashboard to overview/control that boxes.

Webmin is a option, but I want to know is there any alternatives like a ajenti, for example.

Could our community help me to figure it out?

Comment: To help people answer you should clarify what functions you want. You mention Webmin (a solution thats also available on Ubuntu/Debian), any reason for not just using that?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is **zentyal**.

> Zentyal is a Linux small business server, that can be configured as a
>   Gateway, Infrastructure Manager, Unified Threat Manager, Office
>   Server, Unified Communication Server or a combination of them. All
>   network services managed by Zentyal are tightly integrated, automating
>   most tasks. This helps to avoid errors in the network configuration
>   and administration and allows to save time. Zentyal is open source,
>   released under the GNU General Public License (GPL) and runs on top of
>   Ubuntu GNU/Linux.

[image]

[image]

To install in ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install <zentyal-module>
```

The zentyal list modules and the full how to install and configure can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/zentyal.html

---

Another option to use **nagios**.

> Nagios is a powerful monitoring system that enables organizations to
>   identify and resolve IT infrastructure problems before they affect
>   critical business processes.
>
> First launched in 1999, Nagios has grown to include thousands of
>   projects developed by the worldwide Nagios community. Nagios is
>   officially sponsored by Nagios Enterprises, which supports the
>   community in a number of different ways through sales of its
>   commercial products and services.
>
> Nagios monitors your entire IT infrastructure to ensure systems,
>   applications, services, and business processes are functioning
>   properly. In the event of a failure, Nagios can alert technical staff
>   of the problem, allowing them to begin remediation processes before
>   outages affect business processes, end-users, or customers. With
>   Nagios you'll never be left having to explain why an unseen
>   infrastructure outage hurt your organization's bottom line.

[source](http://www.nagios.org/about)

Install nagios in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nagios3
```

It will go through, and ask you about what mail server you want to use:

[image]

Pick one based upon your needs.

[image]

It will then ask you about the domain name you want to have email sent from. Again, fill that out based upon your needs.

It will ask you what password you want to use - put in a secure password. This is for the admin account `nagiosadmin`.

[image]

And then you'll need to verify your password.

Once the install is all done, you can head over to `localhost/nagios3` (or whatever the IP address/domain name of the server you installed it on is) and you'll be asked to enter your password:

[image]

Once you've done that, you're in!

[image]

<sub>Little ugly, huh?</sub>

Nagios automatically adds in the 'localhost' to the config, and does load, current users, disk space, http and ssh checks.

[image]

Now there is one more thing we need to do before nagios is all ready - we need to have it accept external commands so we can acknowledge problems, add comments, etc.

To do that, we need to edit a few files. Start by opening `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg
```

Search for `check_external_commands`, and turn the `check_external_commands=0` into `check_external_commands=1`.

Now, restart apache by running

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Not done yet! We need to edit `/etc/group`. There should be a line like this in there:

```
nagios:x:114
```

Change it to

```
nagios:x:114:www-data
```

Save and close this file.

Now, we need to edit the `/var/lib/nagios3/rw` files permission with:

```
sudo chmod g+x /var/lib/nagios3/rw
```

And then (because of how permissions work) we need to edit the permissions of the directory above that with:

```
sudo chmod g+x /var/lib/nagios3
```

Now, restart nagios with:

```
sudo service nagios3 restart
```

If you use Apache as your web server, restart that also:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

If you can pay Canonical offers a paid service which is fantastic called **landscape**.

> The Landscape systems management tool helps you monitor, manage and
>   update your entire Ubuntu infrastructure from a single interface. Part
>   of Canonical’s Ubuntu Advantage support service, Landscape brings you
>   intuitive systems management tools combined with world-class support.

more about: https://landscape.canonical.com/